# Error running npm Script when starting Docker Container

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

In my DockerFile i have this setup as my command.

`CMD config/startserver.sh`

Having problem getting npm run build to work. I have no problem running npm run build when i go into the conatiner and run docekr exec npm run build manually but for some reason running it inside the .sh causes a problem. Any ideas as to why running npm run build inside an .sh could be causing a problem.

```
npm run build

pm2 start server.js -f -- 5000
pm2 start server.js -f -- 5001
pm2 start server.js -f -- 5002
pm2 start server.js -f -- 5003
pm2 start server.js -f -- 5004

nginx -g "daemon off;"

wait
```

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'run', 'build\r' ]
2 info using npm@6.13.4
3 info using node@v10.19.0
4 verbose config Skipping project config: /home/lgd/.npmrc. (matches userconfig)
5 verbose stack Error: missing script: build
5 verbose stack
5 verbose stack Did you mean this?
5 verbose stack     build
5 verbose stack     at run (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/run-script.js:155:19)
5 verbose stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/run-script.js:63:5
5 verbose stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:116:5
5 verbose stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:436:5
5 verbose stack     at checkBinReferences_ (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:391:45)
5 verbose stack     at final (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:434:3)
5 verbose stack     at then (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:161:5)
5 verbose stack     at ReadFileContext.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:350:20)
5 verbose stack     at ReadFileContext.callback (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:115:16)
5 verbose stack     at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:237:13)
6 verbose cwd /home/lgd
7 verbose Linux 4.19.76-linuxkit
8 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "build\r"
9 verbose node v10.19.0
10 verbose npm  v6.13.4
11 error missing script: build
11 error
11 error Did you mean this?
11 error     build
12 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Can you also add your dockerfile. It could be that you are executing in a wrong folder location.

Comment: Your script has DOS line endings (the command that's getting run is `build\r`).

Comment: Also consider `RUN npm build` in your Dockerfile (at build time, not at startup time), and having the container just run `CMD node server.js 5000`.  If you need multiple copies of the server, or an nginx proxy, run those in separate containers.

Comment: @DavidMaze I have environment variables i pass to the container on run for the build to succeed properly. I'm trying to not to have all my environment variables as plain text in DockerFile. I'm gonna try converting to Linux endings, i think that was the problem.

Comment: @DavidMaze My current setup is that i want to have a Nginx server that is hosted on my Linux machine that servers to multiple instances of this container. This will allow me to update images with no downtime. I have seen the documentation saying to do it your way but i'm not really sure why. I'm new to Docker and PM2 my site has been on Heroku until recently. There's probably something i'm missing.

Comment: "Zero-downtime upgrades" is actually a pretty good reason.  If you have five pm2 processes and nginx all in the same container, you have to stop and restart the whole thing in one batch; but if they're separate containers, you can replace the Node containers one at a time and leave the nginx proxy in place.

Answer (score 0):

Had to revert to calling the script in Docker because I was getting permission errors on my Server when I pushed my container. 
I think David was right and I just needed to fix my line endings.

I ended up changing:

```
CMD config/startserver.sh
```

to

```
CMD [ "npm", "run", "start-production" ]
```

And added to my `package.json` scripts

```
"start-production": "npm run build && config/startserver.sh"
```